# Firebase for react and react native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm planning to write a cross platform app using react native using Firebase for backend. I did some research and found the library called React-Native-Firebase. But this library seems to use native part of firebase(android and ios), and my concern is:

If I use React-Native-Firebase to do backend jobs, will I need to write those logics AGAIN using normal Firebase(web version) for building web app with react?

I thought this way because using firebase seems basically like calling Firebase API's in react native or react code.

Answer (score 1):

There will be some differences but only on how you display the data. The two libraries work the exact same way from my understanding, and in many cases you don't even need the React-Native-Firebase. I recently built an app with only the Firebase node module installed to fetch and upload data to the database. What you miss out on there is the Analytics and other Firebase features which are included in the React-Native-Firebase.

The solution for Backend logic on both device and web is to use Firebase Functions
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

It is really effective and you can call it from both native device and web and have all your logic there.

For fetching data you will probably have to write code separately for both web and native, but you would've had to have some differences anyway. For all other logic that needs to be handled, move it to the Firebase Functions and just call it from the web and native separately and you won't need to rewrite too much code.